# No additional drivers available

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I just bought new computer and installed Ubuntu. It works pretty well, but I can't change drivers because Ubuntu says that there is no drivers available. My graphics card is nVidia GeForce GTX 750 ti gaming edition.

Is something wrong in my computer or is there any other solutions?

Here is other details:
Intel® Core™ i5-3570K CPU @ 3.40GHz × 4 
Disk: 980,2 GB

Answer (score 3):

Available graphics drivers  won't be appear on the additional drivers tab if you fail to add the below to your System.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Now go to Software and Updates and select additional drivers tab. You will see the available options.

Comment: Is this a bug? Do you know why this would be different from the behavior for my previous Nvidia card, where drivers just showed up without a PPA needed?