# Fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 Install - No Additional Drivers Available?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg

I recently installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 on my brand new, self-built, desktop PC. It has an i5-4690k, 8GB DDR3-1600MHz, and an EVGA GeForce GTX 750 Ti FTW:

[image]

I have pretty abysmal frame-rates on everything (Hammerwatch & Minecraft currently), so I figured I'd look into getting the proprietary drivers, which I was told are supposed to improve FPS quite a bit.

However, when I go to **Software & Updates** > **Additional Drivers** I get nothing:

[image: wut]

I noticed on [this question here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459593/no-additional-drivers-available) (describes my issue almost exactly the same) that I might have to add the xorg-edgers PPA for them to show up. However, I was under the impression that the X-SWAT & Xorg-edgers PPAs were dangerous for system stability.

Is this the case, or do I have to add one or the other of these PPAs to get the drivers?

As a side note, I'm pretty sure that Ubuntu is, indeed, using my GTX 750 Ti, as the output of `lspci -vnnn | perl -lne 'print if /^\d+\:.+(\[\S+\:\S+\])/' | grep VGA` returns this:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] [10de:1380] (rev a2) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
```

**EDIT**:

It would appear that this is actually a fairly common bug, just from my googling about.

Here's a [Launchpad bug report that describes it perfectly](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-drivers-common/+bug/1351699). They mention that adding the xorg-edgers PPA and installing the nvidia-340 drivers resolves this issue.

However, I'm still a tad nervous about enabling a testing repository - is it safe enough to enable the repository, install the driver, and then disable the repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading the newest drivers straight from NVIDIA from [here](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/73666/en-us) and installing them manually. Obviously, this won't automatically update in the future (AFAIK).

The path I had to take was actually quite convoluted, involving adding the `nomodeset` flag to GRUB, then killing `lightdm`, and then running the installer. I followed some suggestions from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451221/ubuntu-14-04-install-nvidia-driver) and was provided some help from [@Mateo](https://askubuntu.com/users/47291/mateo) and [@Seth](https://askubuntu.com/users/44179/seth) in chat.