# How to set up nVidia Optimus in 14.04

Tags: nvidia-optimus, bumblebee, cuda

I have attempted to get my nVidia 970M working in 14.04 but despite the many (many!) methods out there, none seems to work for me.

Using the instruction from [How to set up nVidia Optimus/Bumblebee in 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/452556/how-to-set-up-nvidia-optimus-bumblebee-in-14-04) on clean install, I got the following outputs:

```
$ optirun -vv firefox
[   81.193199] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[   81.193469] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...
[   81.193476] [DEBUG]Active configuration:
[   81.193478] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
[   81.193480] [DEBUG] X display: :8
[   81.193481] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /usr/lib/nvidia-331:/usr/lib32/nvidia-331
[   81.193483] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket
[   81.193485] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto
[   81.193487] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy
[   81.193489] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options:
[   81.193491] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/primus:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/primus
[   81.193689] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge primus
[   81.617084] [INFO]Response: No - error: Could not load GPU driver

[   81.617093] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver

[   81.617095] [DEBUG]Socket closed.
[   81.617105] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
[   81.617108] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.


$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)

$ lspci | grep NVIDIA
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 13d8 (rev a1)
```

When I try to go via the nvidia-prime route using instructions from [How to install and configure Nvidia Optimus driver on Ubuntu](http://xmodulo.com/install-configure-nvidia-optimus-driver-ubuntu.html),

1. Additional Drivers list is empty even after following [No additional drivers available](https://askubuntu.com/questions/459593/no-additional-drivers-available)
2. selecting the nvidia card produces a blank screen, which in itself is not a problem, but suggest that something is not working.
3. lightdm doesn't restart when I try to switch back to the Intel card.

P.S. I only want to use CUDA, if that can simplify things.